# SAGA IDW interpolation algorithm has been changed?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga, inverse-distance-weighted

Yesterday, I try after a long time to make an IDW interpolation on a point layer in Qgis 2.18 with SAGA tools. I use same parameters as before on Qgis 2.14, but the result is quite different. Raster isn't smooth and all points are very visible on it.

[image: IDW interpolation]

Has SAGA IDW interpolation has been changed between these 2 versions?

Comment: How about changing the `Resampling method` (in Advanced parameters) to `Nearest Neighbour`?

Comment: Which parameter is it for resampling ? because parameter names aren't explicit in IDW interpolation window. I have `Search Range` with `Maximum number of nearest points` and `Number of points` with `Maximum number of nearest points` too. I already use these 2 settings...

Comment: which version of 2.18 are you on? If you're on 2.18.10 or later QGIS may be using a different version of SAGA. Do you know what the **Inverse Distance Power** and **Inverse Distance weighting** values before and after?

Comment: I'm on QGIS 2.18.9 with SAGA 2.2.3 and interpolation "do not work". But I don't know Qgis and Saga versions when interpolation was working well. I only know values of parameters for old version. For **Inverse Distance Power : 2** and I haven't  **Inverse Distance weighting** but **Distance Weighting** on **inverse distance to a power**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see distance-based interpolation formula in following link:

http://www.gitta.info/ContiSpatVar/en/html/Interpolatio_learningObject2.xhtml

where p is **distance weighting exponent** and it probably was the parameter that is different between these 2 SAGA versions.

So, it's relatively easy to code this algorithm in PyQGIS. As follow, it has inside three arbitrary points to be interpolated and it was used a five points layer as base of interpolation.

```
from math import sqrt

def idw(pt, points, z, beta):

    n = len(points)

    sum_inv_dist_z = 0
    sum_inv_dist = 0

    for i in range(n):

        inv_dist = 1/(sqrt(pt.sqrDist(points[i])))**beta
        inv_dist_z = z[i]*inv_dist

        sum_inv_dist_z += inv_dist_z
        sum_inv_dist += inv_dist

    z_j = sum_inv_dist_z/sum_inv_dist

    return z_j

#Code starts here

layer = iface.activeLayer()

features = layer.getFeatures()

#get features for geometry
points = [feature.geometry().asPoint() for feature in features]

#get features for attributes
features = layer.getFeatures()

attr = [feature.attributes() for feature in features]

#selecting elevation field
z = [item[4] for item in attr]

print z

#set beta value
beta = 2

#defining arbitrary points
pt = [QgsPoint(398574.065172, 4452409.334),
      QgsPoint(412049.303287, 4447317.71399),
      QgsPoint(434741.145557, 4435557.70814)]

#calculating z value for each point
for item in pt:
    print idw(item, points, z, beta)
```

Used layers look as at following image where green points will be interpolated and blue points have z values.

[image]

After running code at Python Console of QGIS I got:

```
[1694.0, 1700.0, 1368.0, 1439.0, 1368.0, 1943.0]
1709.79209934
1622.47616106
1436.15697073
```

where it can be observed that obtained values are similar to neighbors.

However, it's more useful when above algorithm was coded in my own IDW plugin to get a complete raster (perfectly aligned with base raster). In following composition I used 25 points and p different values (0.1, 0.5 and 2). It can be observed that p parameter is a smoothed factor.

[image]

By the way, my results are identical to obtained with IDW QGIS tool; except my interpolated rasters were perfectly aligned with base raster.